# What can replace milk in crepes?

Tags: substitutions, milk, crepe

I want to make crepes, but I am out of milk.  Can I still make crepes?  What can replace milk in this application?

I do have yogurt, beer, eggs, cream, butter, flour, salt, and sugar.

Comment: I don't know whether it would work but if I was desperate I would experiment a bit and would try either using water or diluting the yoghurt with water to make a runnier but creamy liquid.

Comment: Step 1: Drink all the beer.  Step 2: Now you don't care about crepes.

Comment: I bet coconut milk would add a special richness to the batter. Anyone tried this? Ok, I'll try it and get back!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try watered down cream, as you'll still get some of the milkfat, but you don't want quite as much.

Water would probably also work for your crepes, although it would change the taste.

Comment: Watering down the cream heavily will get approximately the same amount of fat, but not of protein.  I might do this if I were desperate, but really the only thing you can water down to get milk is evaporated milk.

Comment: Crepes are very forgiving, though...  Watered-down cream or cream mixed with yogurt (PLAIN yogurt) might work just fine.

Comment: I ended up going with everything: cream, beer, and yogurt.  They were very light (from all the beer?) but otherwise tasted pretty good.

Answer (score 4):

This might sound nutty, but do you have cashew or almonds? I typically have a stash (though unroasted, unsalted isn't often in the house). You can search around for a recipe for making milk from nuts though:

> Put 1/2 cup raw pecans, almonds, walnuts, Brazil nuts, etc., into a blender
>   container. Process until ground. Add 1/2 cup water and process at low speed
>   for a few seconds, then turn blender to high. Blend for a couple of
>   minutes, then add 1 1/2 cups water. Blend well.([from here](http://www.paleofood.com/nmilks.htm))

Comment: Pun intended?  Seriously though, nut milk might make a dessert crepe extremely tasty.

Comment: @Mrs. *Nutty indeed*, as far as /planning/ around using nut milk you could definitely do some really rich ones; but nut milk could also be used for savory crepes as well, ie spinach and cashew?

Answer (score 0):

Out of

- yogurt
- beer
- eggs
- cream
- butter
- flour
- salt
- sugar

I would say cream is a perfect milk replacement (given you have enough). The crepes will probably taste even better a well.

Will they contain more fat?

YES.

Should you care (this one time when you are out of milk)?

Answer (score -1):

Well, since some are saying to use non fat or almond milk, I am going to experiment with rice milk, which I find quite tasty.